# Modal from bootstrap not showing up, Visual studio, js, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vba, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

So i have this simple validation condition, if the lenght of one of the values its equal to 10 or 11 or 12 then it should display the value, i alreaddy debugg it and it seems it is indeed going through the condition, another modal i have in the same view its working so its not an incorrect style call, already ckecked some questions and tutorials and still not able to make it work.

here is the js code where its supposed to call it:

```
var cel = document.forms["FormularioAlta"]["cel"].value;
            var celconfirmacion = document.forms["FormularioAlta"]["celconfirmacion"].value;
            var ocr = document.forms["FormularioAlta"]["ocr"].value;
            var ocrconfirmacion = document.forms["FormularioAlta"]["ocrconfirmacion"].value;
            var flag = true;




            if (cel.length != 10 || celconfirmacion.length != 10) {

                flag = false;

            }
            if (ocr.length == 10 || ocr.length == 11 || ocr.length == 12 || ocrconfirmacion.length == 10 || ocrconfirmacion.length == 11 || ocrconfirmacion.length == 12) {

                //alert("los OCR deben de tener solamente una longitud de 9 o 13 digitos");
                flag = false;
                $("#ModalErrorOCR").modal("show");


            }
```

and here is where i declare the modal:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="ModalErrorOCR" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Error</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Los OCR deben de tener  una longitud de 9 o 13 digitos unicamente.&hellip;</p>
      </div>

         <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>

      </div>

    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: have you confirmed the modal element exists? Any errors thrown?

Comment: what do you mean with modal element? and no, no error thrown,. wierd thing is i have another modal and that one is working with another condition, so i tried to see if my condition was working, and indeed, it displays the alert y have commented there, but the modal still not showing, already checked for some sintaxys mistakes but im not able to find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I pasted your code into JSFiddle, I got an error on the first line of Javascript. However, when I removed that line and just pasted in the HTML of the modal and the code to show it, everything worked properly. Take a look at this fiddle and you can see it working.

http://jsfiddle.net/pup3jykb/1/

```
$("#ModalErrorOCR").modal("show");
```

Make sure you don't have any other errors on the page preventing the modal from appearing

Comment: mmm not able to fin de code, i will post it completely to see if sombody can help.

Comment: There is another issue I just thought of. All `.value` calls to `<input>` elements return a string. If you want to compare the value against an integer, you first need to use `parseInt()` to convert the string to an integer

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt